# Isn't message passing between two nodes in ROS same as interprocess communication between two programs in linux same?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make robot with BBB. It looks like without using ROS also different programs can be run in BBB in linux and than the outputs can be sent to other programs at same time, so why is their any difference in ROS message passing system between two nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234855/isn%27t-message-passing-between-two-nodes-in-ros-same-as-interprocess-communication-between-two-programs-in-linux-same?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct, the message-passing portion of ROS is inter-process communication (IPC).

I'm not sure which other IPC mechanisms you're looking at, but ROS provides the following additional features in addition to just passing messages:

- message type checking (type name and message version)
- support for many languages: C++, Pytho, Lisp, Java and more!
- seamless use of language-native data structures (no need to explicitly serialize)
- seamless use of multiple publishers and subscribers on a topic (IPC channel)
- Introspection of the type, content and rate of messages on a topic (rostopic command-line tool)
- very easy to create and use multiple topics
- easily expands to work across a network, with no changes to your nodes

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3